# How to correctly use cv2.DrawMarker function?

Tags: python, opencv, floating-point, integer, typeerror

I'm getting the error shown below when I try to call my `cv2.drawMarker` function.

```
...
line_type=cv2.LINE_AA)
TypeError: integer argument expected, got float.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

This is my function call

```
    for keypoint in keypoints:
        im_with_keypoints = cv2.drawMarker(im_with_keypoints,
                                           keypoint.pt,
                                           (0, 0, 255),
                                           markerType=cv2.MARKER_CROSS,
                                           markerSize=30,
                                           thickness=2,
                                           line_type=cv2.LINE_AA)
```

This is the documentation for the function from the official OpenCV site.

```
void cv::drawMarker ( Mat &             img,
                      Point             position,
                      const Scalar &    color,
                      int               markerType = MARKER_CROSS,
                      int               markerSize = 20,
                      int               thickness = 1,
                      int               line_type = 8 
)
```

I've tried changing from

```
line_type  = cv2.LINE_AA
```

to

```
line_type = int(0)
```

to try and force the argument type, but I'm still getting the same error.

I've tried to look for other code examples but `cv2.LINE_AA` is supposed to work. I'm still getting the same error with my int(..) casting so i'm not sure where to go from here...

Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: Is it that your keyPoints are float rather than integer?

Comment: Oh ***** how could I miss that out. 
Thank you, that solves the problem!!

edit: I need someone to answer it so I can mark the question as solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logical reason for your error could only be that your `keypoints` are `float` and not `integer` dtype, as you've correctly passed the expected types for all other params.
You can convert the dtype using `astype`:

```
keypoints = keypoints.astype(np.int32)
```

A good tip when debugging these errors is to look at the previous lines, or the other params if the reported error line looks fine.